# deleting and returning data in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have the following problem: my table is big enought (millions of data rows), this is temporary data which I process. I need to select max and min of one column accrding to some criteria, process this information and remove data according to the same criteria. Actually, the simplest implementation looks like:

```
select max(col), min(col) from _TABLE_ where _CONDITION_;
...
delete from _TABLE_ where _CONDITION_;
```

table is big, and when I process it, quering that way in cycle, it takes some time. I thought I can optimize it using "returning" in delete, like

```
delete from _TABLE_ where _CONDITION_ returning max(col), min(col);
```

it would be absolutely what I need, but... it does not work at all :) talking that I can't use aggregate functions in returning clause...

is there any good way to improve two queries (selecting max/min of data and deleting the same data) making one query instead? Any trick?

thank you in advance for any information,
Maxym

Comment: Are the _CONDITIONS_ mutually exclusive and relatively low in number?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? Actually "col".. hm, in reality I have two columns, which represent coordinate of point (latitude and longitude), so I select delete all points from table according to some rectangle, but I have to know what was the min/max longitude and longitude of deleted points (real, because approx I could take rectangle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function like this:

```
create temporary table test (value int);
insert into test select generate_series(1,100);

create or replace function delete_even_from_test_and_return_min_deleted()
  returns int as
$$
declare
  _value record;
  min int;
begin
  min=X'7FFFFFFF'; -- INT_MAX
  for _value in
    delete from test where value%2=0 returning value
  loop
    if min>_value.value then
      min=_value.value;
    end if;
  end loop;
  return min;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select count(*) from test;
100

select delete_even_from_test_and_return_min_deleted();
2

select count(*) from test;
50
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
with foo as(delete from table where _CONDITION_ returning col)
select max(col), min(col) from foo
```

Comment: why only from 9.1? the idea is to use CTE function, right? it was enabled for instance in 8.4 too.

Comment: yes, you are right. I think you cannot do WITH (...) DELETE/INSERT before 9.1 : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html . I just mixed things up, thanks!